# How did O'Neill guess there would be a raid in "The Nox?"

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, goauld

In the season one episode of Stargate Sg-1, “The Nox”, how did O’Neill know that there would be a raid right when Nafrayu was revived?

Comment: My memory might fail me here, but before that scene, didn't one of Apophis's jaffa escape with the knowledge that the Nox can turn invisible? Apophis, being after this ability and learning the truth from his jaffa, would launch an assault to claim it. The clues were all there for Jack to piece together.

Comment: Yes, but it was almost as if there was some sort of trigger because they started the raid almost at the exact same time that they started reviving Nafrayu. If I remember correctly he said that they would try to get to them just when they started. It’s also rather odd that they were able to coordinate the attack with the revival. Did they have a scout?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O'Neill recognised that the reason that Apophis injured **but didn't kill** Nafrayu (and then left him in a clearing where he could easily be found) is that it's a fairly unimaginative ruse. The Nox, quite predictably, will heal the child, thus revealing themselves. Apophis and his henchman can then attack with impunity, presumably having posted lookouts to identify when they become visible.

> **TEAL'C:** *Shak'l has told Apophis of your ritual…that you cannot remain hidden when you perform it.*